# creating page using bootstrap with specific font and style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use font `Orator Std` but it does not appear corretly. 
more,

1. when I tested the code on local server, font size was near to what I want in image here, when tested on jsfiddle, font size changes for element and position also change. any reason for this?
2. why hr does not appear in yellow
3. How to last to character in vuvua specific color?

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/ewGXv/

I want my page to look similar to :

[image]

Comment: Here a Fiddle to help you : http://jsfiddle.net/ewGXv/ good luck !

Comment: @Aliassse: dude, copy pasted my own fiddle : )

Comment: F*** ! Mishandling ! Sorry, I'll update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the font is not a standard font available on any system. To include a non-standard font you will to reference that font and force it be downloaded if not available.

For example, to use a font from Google's Font API you can:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
        font-size: 48px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Sample text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you specifically need Orator and it is not available for hosted loading at a service like Google's Font API, then you will need to download and host it yourself.

ADDED:
Although not perfect this is 90% of what you need. I'll leave you to tweak the layout and styling to your needs. [A rough example of the layout](http://www.askthepigeon.com/test_font.html)

Andy

Comment: I have updated my original post to show how the last chars of each line can be made yellow and how to deal with a yellow rule.

Comment: Just "show source" on the link above and you can see how I did it.

Comment: I guess it was because of script I used to make first charcter caps

Comment: Sorry you're links are local to your machine so I can't see them. If you are using script to modify the first chars that maybe interfering. Nice solution here might help. http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?780836-CSS-Target-the-First-Letter-of-Every-Word